# NGINX HTTP Request To Linked Container

Tags: node.js, http, docker, nginx, containers

This is my docker-compose file which starts up a `NodeJS/PM2` container and a `React/Nginx` container on the same host.

```
version: '3'
services:
  nodejs:
    image: nodejs_pm2:1.00
    container_name: NODE_CONTAINER
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    build:
      context: ./nodejs
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nodejs
  react:
    image: react_nginx:1.00
    container_name: REACT_CONTAINER
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    build:
      context: ./react-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-react
    depends_on:
     - nodejs
```

As you can see, my `react` service `depends_on nodejs`. This should link the containers, correct?

**Question 1)** Assuming that's true, what's the proper way to make an HTTP request to my node backend?

Here's what I've tried doing to my nginx config file:

```
upstream backend {
    server nodejs:8000
  }

  server {
    listen 3000;

    location ~ ^/api/[0-9a-z]+/$ {
      proxy_pass http://backend/;
      include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }

    location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }
```

This does not work. In fact this totally prevents the front end from showing up at all. What I'm trying to do is something like this `axios.get("http://backend/api/*")` from my react app. I've looked up several stackoverflow post and none of them seem to have worked for me.

**Question 2)** Follow up question, what's the point of linking containers if 
 two containers live on the same host, couldn't I just do a request to `localhost:port` like normal?

Answer (score 0):

you actually have 3 questions:

**Question 0** This should link the containers, correct?

Nope, `depends_on` defines container dependency (eg, wait for container A to start before container B), not links

**Question 1** what's the proper way to make an HTTP request to my node backend?

Your 2 containers can connect to each other using the `container_name` property
So for your nginx.config, you should be able to connect to the nodejs container thru `NODE_CONTAINER:8000`

**Question 2*** what's the point of linking containers if two containers live on the same host, couldn't I just do a request to localhost:port like normal?

Please refer to this, it will explain the container networking and linking concepts better than me https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: I tried doing `NODE_CONTAINER:8000` in my http request and got `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: Are you testing those connectivities from the docker host or from inside the container?

- `NODE_CONTAINER` will only get resolved from inside the containers as they are automatically connected to a default bridged docker network
- `http://localhost:8000` works since it that port was exposed in the `docker-compose` file

For troubleshooting, you can try to get inside one of the container by:

- check the container ids or name: `docker-ps`
- `docker exec -it <container id or name> /bin/sh